# Making a user profile , clashing of fields

Tags: django, django-models

**Users class**:

```
   class Users(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')
        user_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

I am  getting error like this :

**ERRORS:**

```
myWebsite.Users.user_id: (models.E006) The field 'user_id' clashes with the field 'user' from model 'myWebsite.users'.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience but it was clashing with user_id field in the parent class of User:

new class **Users:**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')
    user_Id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Changed user_id to user_Id and all works fine.

Thanks BTW for reading by.